# Toolbar does not Hide/Shown on Scrolling in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview

I'm trying to auto hide and show depends on scrolling of TextView implemented in ViewPager. But, Toolbar never hides on scrolling.
Main XML activity_data_display.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/activity_drawer"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.regio.developers.upasana.DataDisplayActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_data_display"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/data_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's the layout that is inflated in ViewPager
data_swipe_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dataviewpager_textview"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="35dp"
        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**added**
Toolbar Layout file
toolbar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
 app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Please solve my problem?

I've tried different ways to make it work like using NestedScrollView in Main XML file. But, it just does not help.

Please try implementing yourself then give me solution for this.

Remember I've used TextView which contains hundreds of of line of text.

**Also,** how to implement ScrollBar which can be drag-able manually for the TextView in ViewPager?

Comment: In toolbar, you have to use app:layout_scrollFlags.check this [link](http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout)

Comment: I've used app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" in toolbar_layout file

Answer (score 2):

You are using the included layout of toolbar you should make this property app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

for the AppBarLayout or write that code of toolbar in AppBarLayout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Also can you tell me how to show Scrollbar?

Comment: put all of it in a <ScrollView></ScrollView> or you can set the property of the layout as scrollable. Hope that works in your case

Answer (score 1):

```
Check this.
 it is working
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarsdfs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dataviewpager_textview"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="35dp"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```